# Subtracting time format variables

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have a variable assigned as start time and want to subtract the same with current system time inorder to calculate total ours.

eg:

from datetime import datetime

start = "9:45:00"

total_hours = start - datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

is this a correct approach?

Comment: You're better off converting your time to a datetime object with something like `datetime.strptime('9:45:00 02/12/2020', '%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%Y')` and then doing your math with that. Your example doesn't work because you're attempting to subtract 2 strings.

Comment: Axe319 Should I convert current time also in the above format?

Comment: Well, your time needs a date attached to it in order for it to be able to catch all possibilities. If you simply say `start = "9:45:00"` there is no way for the system to know if you're talking about today's date or yesterday's date so it's easier to specify the date. Assuming you're somehow placing this into your start variable in this format `start = '9:45:00 02/12/2020'` you can get your difference by doing `difference = datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%Y') `. From here you can get your seconds elapsed in the form of a float with `difference.total_seconds()`.